# Хостинг с PayPal оплатой

Tags: paypal, хостинг

Всем привет. Собственно сабж. Есть несколько вариантов, но мне интересно мнение тех, кто пользовался.

Comment: Есть такой же интерес. Нужен российский хостинг с возможностью оплатить Pay Pal. Есть такие?

Comment: Понятия не имею по какому принципу они там сортируются, но вот вам целый список, который я достал по нехитрому запросу *хостинг paypal*:

http://ru.hostings.info/paypal-hosting.html

Постарайтесь в следующий раз не задавать вопрос ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CloudVPS](https://cloudvps.com). Странные голландцы, но работает неплохо, и стоит недорого.

Answer (score 0):

[Gandi](https://www.gandi.net/hosting/)